# Cannot Open .txt file with ESNote Editor in my app

Tags: java, android

Ive implemented a UI that displays the contents of the /data/data/com.example.motionsense/files/scaninfo/ which is where a list of txt files are located. When one is selected, it opens programs that can display these text files, such as ESNote Editor. However when I try to open a file with ESNote Editor, it displays the error "invalid path" and displays a blank document.

I have opened these text files before with ESNote Editor but it does not work when my application opens a file with it. I think it has something to do with the file pathway, when I click to open a file that is displayed, it does not give the correct path to ESNote Editor in order to open the file. Ive tried to fix the code and logged what I thought could fix the problem but it again comes up with an error in the log and I do not know what to make of it.

```
04-01 21:50:53.101: E/PATHWAY(32762): /data/data/com.example.motionsense/files/scaninfo_01_04_2014_21_37_19
04-01 21:50:53.101: E/LookHere(32762): file:///data/data/com.example.motionsense/files/scaninfo_01_04_2014_21_37_19.txt
```

Does anyone know if this is the problem? I've posted my code below. I am also aware that the file location is in the data/data folder but my phone is rooted and I have tested opening the files with ESNote Editor without using my application and it works.

```
private void getDir(String dirPath) {

        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        fileList = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if (!dirPath.equals(root)) {
            item.add(root);
            fileList.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            fileList.add(f.getParent());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];

            if (!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                fileList.add(file.getPath());
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                } else {
                    item.add(file.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //String s = myPath.getText().subSequence(11,myPath.getText().length());
        Log.e("PATHFOOL", fileList.get(position).replace("//", "/"));
        File file = new File(fileList.get(position)+".txt".replace("//", "/"));
        Log.e("LookHere", Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            if (file.canRead()) {
                // openning

                getDir(fileList.get(position));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle(
                                "[" + file.getName()
                                        + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();


                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "]")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: other apps can't access private files of your application.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by it does not give the correct path.  What is the correct path?  What path does it give instead?

Comment: The correct path is meant to be /data/data/com.example.motionsense/files/scaninfo/ and it gives that but for some reason it does not work. It might be because other applications cant access them in which case ill prob need to have my app display the contents instead of trying to open it with another app.